# Which way consumes less processing in creating controls?

Tags: winforms, dynamically-generated

I need to create 200+ controls in a winform application that has only one form. They will all be grouped in panels.
I have the option to create the controls dynamically in code or statically by dragging them onton the panels. 
I'm trying to find out which way consumes less CPU power and less memory: statically or dynamically.

Or are both ways will consume the same?

thank you in advance

Comment: Will the controls be persisted from multiple instances of the application or are they created each time the app is loaded? If they are created each time are they created up front or as needed?

Comment: I don't need to persist them because the app will only load once and it is the end of the execution.
And I was thinking about only creating the ones that are needed (based on logical algorithms), so each time the form load, it may loads different set of controls than the time before.

Comment: However, there is a factor based on where the components are being streamed from. That's why I asked about storage requirements, if any.

Comment: @ltn nothing is being streamed. The OP is asking whether to use the Visual Studio winforms designer, or manually writing the code to add the controls into the form (which is exactly what the designer generates, by the way).

Comment: ah ok. I thought the question was in regards to rendering the controls at runtime. My bad:)

Comment: It's the same. There's no difference. If you use the Visual Studio winforms designer, it will create all the controls in C# code that will be executed at runtime. If you need something really fast, hardware-accelerated, vector-based, easier to code and maintain, you should forget winforms and switch to any of the current (<10 years old) XAML-Based technologies (such as WPF or WinRT). winforms is innefficient and slow, and doesn't support having too many controls in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of memory and speed, it won't make a noticeable difference whether they are dynamically created or done by a GUI builder.

I'd also be looking at a way to avoid 200 controls on one form (e.g. breaking it into some tabs or similar). The more you can break the problem down, the more attractive GUI builders/drag and drop becomes...